# Sandboxed solutions get all sharepoint lists in sitecollection

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am working with sandboxed solutons.(VS2010 C#) I need to retrieve all lists present in the site collection. I am able to get the lists from the site but not from entire sitecollection like subsites

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteAddress))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                  //how can i get all lists from site and its sub sites?
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
foreach (SPWeb web in SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs)
{
  foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
  {
    // Do work
  }
  web.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll not be able to use the returned list for anything without causing SharePoint to revitalize the disposed web, which then will leak.

Comment: I didn't know that. So SPList got a reference to the original SPWeb object, which will revitalize when it is called upon

Comment: Yes I see, it's a property ParentWeb on SPWeb which will be reopened (m_parentWeb in my dissasembler). Although it seems to do this when it is `null` only. @PerJakobsen you got a text-book solution for this? I see how one could wrap in `using` for each `web`, and then _do work_ inside it, and even use `Event` as a callback. Feel free to edit the post :)

Comment: It very much depends on the classes involved and what you need to do. But I usually prefer to do all the processing while looping through the webs (can be through a delegate). Sometimes it's better to keep the webs for which you return lists alive and dispose them in your own dispose method.

Comment: @PerJakobsen, I have updated the answer with code I hope is safer. Although I love writing code like this: https://gist.github.com/a7c6efb2360382933896 I believe this is more straight forward (and faster, for those that might care :) ).